# Echo en window.location no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo que redireccionar a una página con un usuario en concreto cuando finalice al agregar un profesor. La variable donde tengo el ID del profesor la tengo en php pero no funciona window.location + el echo de la variable php:

```
$("#contact_form_add").on("submit", function(e) {
 var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
 var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
 $.ajax({
   url: formURL,
   type: "POST",
   data: postData,
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#contact_dialog_Add .modal-header .modal-title').html("Result");
        $('#contact_dialog_Add .modal-body').html(data);
        $("#submitForm_Add").remove();
        var delay = 2000;
        setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'teachers.php?id=<?php echo $teacher_id; ?>'  }, delay);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.log(status + ": " + error);
  }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente no te funcionará. window.location es un objeto con múltiples datos, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
window.location.href = "..."
```

Si abres una consola pulsando F12 y escribes window.location, verás todo lo que contiene.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (teacher_class_control.php?=$teacher_id:1100)

Comment: Poniendo "..." me saca al index.php

Comment: Perdona, el ... equivale a lo que tú ya estabas usando. Si pones window.location.href = "https://google.es" te reenviará a google.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné creando una variable JS cogiendo el valor de la php (`var profesor = '<?php echo $get_id; ?>';`) y después simplente `window.location = 'teachers.php?id='+profesor`